# Adding multiple vertices in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, vertices

I created a new polygon feature in QGIS 3.4 using the *add polygon feature* tool. I accidentally clicked the right mouse button to finish creating the feature. **I want to continue being able to add points using one click**. I am able to add new points using the *vertex* tool, but this is much more cumbersome than when using the *add polygon feature* tool because I need to click on the '+' and then click where to add the new vertex (two clicks instead of one).

Is there a way to 'go back' to the functionality of the *add polygon feature* tool, where only one click is needed to add a vertex?

Comment: You can try the [Reshape Feature](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#reshape-features) tool of the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Vertex-Tool and SHIFT-Doubleclick to add vertices at any place. This feature was  reintroduced in 3.6 or 3.8 and backported to the LTR (3.4.13):

[image]

Comment: Out of interest, how did you record that GIF?

Comment: I use screen2gif: https://www.screentogif.com/